# My bootstrap modal only works on the index.html page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

It will not toggle and open on my other 2 pages.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.nick.com/spongebob-squarepants/"><span class="copyright-text">Sponge Bob Square-Pants</span></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

https://lonniewhite.github.io/SpongeBobSquarePants-JobPortfolio/

Comment: Did you include the JS on the other pages?

Answer (score 1):

1) you must include the navbar in every page you want it to appear
2) you have to include bootstrap and jquery in every page that contains the navbar. in the head tag, be sure you wrote this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT:** also, be sure that "portfolio.html" and "contact.html" are written correctly and are in the same folder as index.php